# Activity wait for transition then start timer. min sdk 16

Tags: android, android-activity, transition, oncreate, chronometer

I am using a fade_in and fade_out for my activity transition.
Everything is running ok when I navigate the menus. The problem is that I have 6 buttons that start a specific activity which includes a timer(chronometer).
This activity starts this timer onCreate() method.
So the problem is how to start my timer only after the animation for transition ends?. My timer is running while the animation is still running. Any ways to make this work with min sdk 16?

I am thinking to use a handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
@Override
  public void run(){
   // keep resetting the timer 
 }
 }, 1000);
```

Any others idea?

```
<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
  <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
  <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
  <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
  <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    public void startRepeating(final long repeatEachSeconds,final long repeatForSeconds)
    {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopWatch.resetTime();
                mHandler.postDelayed(this,repeatEachSeconds);
            }
        };

        mRunnable.run();

        Handler stopHandler = new Handler();
        stopHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }
        }, repeatForSeconds);
    }```
````